# Excel search function issues

Tags: excel, vba, search, filter, macros

I am trying to implement a search function into an Excel spreadsheet that displays filtered results. I implemented a basic search bar, but I am having a few problems with it. For example, when I try to search by entering a date, it only works if I enter in the full date (dd/mm/yyyy), but I need to be able to search by year. And searching by price doesn't seem to function properly at all. I also attempted to implement a basic VBA UserForm to handle more advanced range (min/max) searches, but I keeps giving me errors. Here is the spreadheet:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ctb788j2sqrxq0q/CommSales_June2016%20ver%201%20%281%29.xlsm?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I think your date issue is easily solved. When you iterate through the date rows, in addition to matching the full date for the cell content, you can also match for Year(#CellValue#) which will allow you to search by year.

As for price, not exactly sure how you are searching for it in your search bar. The cell is formatted as currency, but reading it programmatically will yield a number. So you might want to convert the content from your search box into an integer for identical comparisons.